# How to circumvent country restrictions without installing software?

Tags: video-streaming, proxy

[HotSpot Shield](http://hotspotshield.com/) sets your computer proxy configuration so you can access sites that wouldn't work if they knew the country where you are at.

But it requires installation.

Web interfaces to proxies like [ZTunnel](http://ztunnel.com) don't forward flash or video streams correctly.

I guess many proxies that I can find on the net won't forward video streams too.

So how to get a list of proxies that will? Or is there any alternative to watch videos that aren't delivered to my country?

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is a VPN provider.

[VyprVPN](https://www.goldenfrog.com/vyprvpn/vpn-service-provider) is reliable, but not cheap (~15USD per month)

there are few free ones, but most of them are slow just not very good.

Answer (score 2):

From what I hear, a VPN works, but a VPN costs money and requires changes to computer's settings. If so, you can use things like VyprVPN and other VPN's.

There are certain proxies that can use video and forward it. This is what you are looking for: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=video+proxies

Another alternative, find a free IP-based proxy, change the network settings to use it and go through that. That requires an IP address, but I would imagine they are probably easily found.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.hidemyass.com for watching country restricted YouTube videos.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for Youtube, I use [Youtube Mirror](http://www.tubemirror.com/) which will bypass these geographic restrictions without a sweat! You can try it out too, let me know what you think of it!

Comment: This is a spam site. Locks up your browser.